# Suggestion: Native or Web App depending upon my idea?

Tags: android, mongodb, cordova, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

- **What I want to develop: Crude Overview?**
  Suppose 10 web links present on my (native/web) app, and user will scroll through links. And when user clicks on any of the link, it will open that website. And user might wish to close this website and again views the list of those URLs on my app and the cycle may go on as per his wish. Also, user can create custom list of those links. Also, these lists will be updated regularly, may be on monthly basis. Which I guess I just need to update data files and not app.
  No, it is not similar to browser bookmarks but in very crude terms you can relate it. Anyways, I will accessing user's bookmarks with his permission which I guess can be easily done with the APIs available.
- **Right now,  technologies in my mind.**
  **1)** Phonegap ( to be precise, its phonegap build - as I don't have MAC) with JQuery mobile and deploy as native app,**or**
  **2)** SenchaTouch and deploy as web app or native app using sencha cmd.
  **3)** I want to use MongoDB along with above 1st or 2nd option. **Is it required or JSON can suffice?** Also, I may need some security by encrypting this data while storage at user's mobile and also while collecting user's custom lists.
  **4)** In future, I would also need Node.js for the purpose of collecting MongoDB or JSON data files in above 3rd point. Is there any other way so that it can be integrated with phonegap or senchaTouch.

**Please suggest things if existing resources can help me develop my idea and guide me what to use!**

**Note:** All technologies I am picking up are focused on single code base with minimal focus on platform specific changes-iOS/android/Windows/Blackberry.

- **I want to go for Native app rather than web app. Why?**
  **1)** I feel that it would perform faster if I deploy my idea as android/iOS/Windows app rather than web application.
  **2)** My cost of hosting the application on server will go to null because I am using local storage of the user's mobile.
  **3)** Since I want a feature in my app which stores user custom settings so it would be better if I deploy it as mobile app rather than web app so that I don't have to maintain user specific settings which may make my DataBase hosted on server to grow immense in future.
  **4)** Also,I feel that there is no sense in hosting this application on a dedicated server because there would be less user interaction with my backend. But later I would plan a feature to collect data/settings done by user to improve feed for which I think I need to use Node.js. But then also there is no requirement of hosting frontend to a dedicated server. Hence, I can use dedicated server to serve my own purpose of analytics to improve feed rather than service user's purpose of unnecessary access to my web application always through the server and fetching lists of links which are maintained on server in custom manner for him.
- **My dilemma!**
  My above points are valid to prefer deploying as native app over rather than web app. But I feel what if I keep my app as offline web app which runs on the default browser of the user but loads the jquery and other data and scripts from the storage in mobile. **Is this possible?** I am unaware of this.
  If this is available then it is the best thing for me to adopt as my application redirects to other websites. Because, if I am deploying my app as native app then it would ruin user experience of opening my app and selecting an option whose URL opens up in default user's mobile browser which is a different app and then there are many chances that user will switch back to my app and then again he would be redirected to that mobile browser. And obviously I cannot develop my own browser in my app as I would have to develop several things from security and other perspective which would be a cumbersome task. So, having my offline web app will be opened in user's default browser itself without annoying him to switch back and forth between my app and browser as in previous case and thus creating seamless experience.

Also, I am not sure whether we can create offline inbuilt browser plugins as we can do in chrome browser on desktop. If so, then I think I would have to concentrate differently on different mobile browsers Safari, Chrome, mozilla which I feel is not worthy. **Please throw some light on this for me.**

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why people are downvoting my question as I feel that it is kind of unique question.

**Here is what I found more and with the help of my friend**

**1)** I don't have to use MongoDB as my application is not much complex. So simple JSON will suffice.
**2)** I'll be using Phonegap for android and windows phone and phonegap build for iOS along with jQMobile. So the app will be in the native form only.
**3)** I'll be using inApp browser for seamless experience although it is not as perfect as having my idea as web app.
**4)** No need for senchaTouch as it is heavier than phonegap and not required for me idea.
**5)** My next look forward is comparing the above points with offline web app built using JQMobile and JSON and finally whatever I decide I will share.

**EDIT:**
**I am finally going with phonegap for native deploy rather than offline web app or web app hosted on server** for reasons that I found on several blogs.
People downvoted my ques so I feel that it is not worth writing answer further but if you want the detailed reason you can always add a comment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely go for web. It is cross platform. If you do an android App, or iOS App, they are restricted to the specific devices. So I definitely recommend Web App

Comment: Not exactly. If I am able to deploy my app on major platforms which are android, iOS, windows and blackberry then I am fine. And it can be done using phonegap or senchatouch. So, the reason that you raised is ruled out. And best thing is that I just have to code in web technologies and have to maintain a single code base.